# Efficiently determine type

Tags: c#, algorithm, type-conversion

I'm faced with the prospect of using a factory method like below to effect setter based DI (because Entity Framework prevents me from using constructor based DI). So when an object is materialized in EF I call the method below to do the setter DI.

```
public void AttachKeyHolder(ILocalizableEntity localizableEntity)
        {
            var ft = (localizableEntity as FeeType);
            if (ft != null)
            {
                localizableEntity.KeyHolder = new FeeTypeKeyHolder();
                return;
            }

            var other = (localizableEntity as OtherType);
            if (other != null)
            {
                localizableEntity.KeyHolder = new OtherTypeKeyHolder();
                return;
            }

            // And on and on and on for every applicable type            
        }
```

I don't like this because it becomes a n-based problem whereby if I have 20 types that need this setter injection then whichever one is type checked in 20th place takes 20 times the amount of time to check as the first type check and since Im doing this every single time an object is materialized in EF it will likely not scale.

So Im looking for a better algorithm. The previous "solution" was to just assign the appropriate KeyHolder in the constructor of the associated object as below:

```
public FeeType()
{
    this.KeyHolder = new FeeTypeKeyHolder();
}
```

This still seems like the most runtime efficient solution and one I'm still leaning very strongly towards regardless of testability due to potentially massive effect setter based DI will likely have with the above factory method. I'd really likely to decouple these classes but not at the expense of the scalability for this web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark properties you need to set via DI with your attribute, like `[Inject]`, and then in desired place (like constructor) call helper method like `MyHelper.InjectProperties(this)`. In helper you can get attributes with [Inject] and resolve their values directly from constructor.

Most of IoC/DI frameworks supports property injection in a performance effective way, so in best of worlds you won't need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: I can't readily see how this helps me. Can you please explain a little further? If I use MyHelper.InjectProperties, Im hiding a dependency (this time on MyHelper) and I would still have to do a type lookup within InjectProperties.... this time with an additional performance hit of using reflection to pull attributed properties.  Happy to admit that I may be missing something here.

Comment: In real life you have really strict type set, so you can build runtime cache for Type -> Inject properties. Instead of `this.Prop = new MyType()` I advice resolving particular type directly from container - thus you will use the same container for all dependencies. MyHelper is 'better' dependency here, as container still owns creation of particular instances - in your approach, you are hiding dependencies AND own creation of that dependencies, which I consider worse from design perspective (cont)

Comment: And again, attribute injection should be supported in most frameworks. If you do not own creation of an object, the only way to fill dependecies is from inside object - so you will have to do something like MyHelper.Inject from inside object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure this is going to have such a bad performance impact. I would doubt so.

Anyway, you can use Visitor patter to implement double dispatch, so instead of 20 test for type of the object, you invoke 2 virtual methods, that is two lookups in virtual methods tables, which **might** be faster than 20 tests, however there is the overhead of two indirect function calls, stack frame allocation for each of them, etc. But again, do we really want to go so deep in case of a C# project with Entity Framework?

Example:

```
class Visitor {
   public virtual void Visit(FeeType f) {}
   public virtual void Visit(OtherType t) {}
}

class abstract BaseType { public abstract void Accept(Visitor v); }

class FeeType : BaseType {
   public override void Accept(Visitor v) { v.Visit(this); }
}

class OtherType : BaseType {
   public override void Accept(Visitor v) { v.Visit(this); }
}

class DIVisitor : Visitor {
   public virtual void Visit(FeeType f) { f.KeyHolder = new ... }
   public virtual void Visit(OtherType t) { t.KeyHolder = new ... }
}

public void AttachKeyHolder(ILocalizableEntity localizableEntity)
{
   var ft = (localizableEntity as TypeBase);
   ft.Accept(new DIVisitor());
}
```

You can also implement the lookup for the correct method based on type through hashing.

```
HashMap<Type, Action<BaseType>> actions;
actions.Add(typeof(FeeType), x => { ((FreeType)x).KeyHolder = new .... });
...
actions[ft.GetType()].Invoke(ft);
```

Comment: +1 For another way of looking at it. As you say it's workable but perhaps a bit OTT.